Position measurement and probability
I am following Modern Quantum Mechanics by Sakurai (second edition) and the book first discusses discrete variables and generalize the result to continuous spectra. In the section 'Position Eigenkets and Position Measurements' on page 41, an arbitrary physicl state $|{\alpha}\rangle$ is expanded in terms of the position eigenkets {|x''$\rangle$} as
$$ |{\alpha}\rangle = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dx'' |x' \rangle \langle x'| \alpha \rangle . $$
Now a detector that clicks when the particle is within a narrow interval around x' is employed to measure the position. The detector clicks when a particle  is in the interval ($x-\Delta/2$, $x+\Delta/2$). When a count is registered in such a detector, the state described above falls into the state (let's call it $|\alpha' \rangle$) given by
$$ |\alpha' \rangle = \int_{x'-\Delta/2}^{x'+\Delta/2} dx'' |x'' \rangle \langle x''|\alpha \rangle . $$
Assuming that $ \langle x''|\alpha \rangle $ doesn't change appreciably within the narrow interval, the probability for the detector to click is given by
$$ {|\langle x'|\alpha \rangle |}^2 \Delta. $$
My attempt to reproduce the result: since $|\alpha' \rangle$ is the result of measurement of position on the state $|\alpha \rangle$, by postulate of QM, the probability of the system to jump into the $|\alpha' \rangle$ state  upon measurement is given by ${|\langle \alpha'|\alpha \rangle |}^2 $. Evaluating $\langle \alpha'|\alpha \rangle$,
$$ \langle \alpha'|\alpha \rangle= \int_{x'-\Delta/2}^{x'+\Delta/2} dx'' \langle\alpha|x'' \rangle\langle x''| \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dx' |x' \rangle \langle x'| \alpha \rangle  $$
$$ = \int_{x'-\Delta/2}^{x'+\Delta/2} dx'' \langle\alpha|x'' \rangle \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dx' \langle x''|x' \rangle \langle x'| \alpha \rangle  $$
$$ = \int_{x'-\Delta/2}^{x'+\Delta/2} dx'' \langle\alpha|x'' \rangle \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dx' \delta_{x'',x'} \langle x'| \alpha \rangle $$
$$ = \int_{x'-\Delta/2}^{x'+\Delta/2} dx'' \langle\alpha|x'' \rangle \langle x''|\alpha \rangle $$
$$ = {|\langle x'|\alpha \rangle |}^2 \Delta, $$
where $\langle x''|\alpha \rangle = \langle x'|\alpha \rangle$ in the interval due to the assumption made earlier .This result matches the probability given in the book but this is only $\langle \alpha'|\alpha \rangle$ and not ${|\langle \alpha'|\alpha \rangle |}^2 $ which would be the probability of being found in the state $|\alpha' \rangle$. Where did I go wrong?

Hint: Your post-measurement state $|\alpha^\prime\rangle$ must be normalized- yours is not, as far as I can see. Everything should work out then.

@TobiasFünke I missed that, thank you for pointing it out. Tried normalizing it and ended up with $ \langle \alpha' | \alpha' \rangle  = \int_{x'-\Delta/2}^{x'+\Delta/2} dx''  \langle \alpha | x'' \rangle  \int_{x'-\Delta/2}^{x'+\Delta/2} dx' \delta (x''-x') \langle x' | \alpha \rangle $ which I don't really know how to simplify further due to the delta function inside the second integral and the bounds of x'' and x' being the same interval. Any hints on how to continue? Thank you!

Well, why can't you simplify with the delta function, I don't understand your comment, sorry? It should work without problems--just throw out one integral and put $x^{\prime\prime}=x^\prime$, no? Note that $\int^b_a \delta(x-x_0) f(x)=f(x_0)$ if $x_0 \in (a,b)$, roughly speaking.

@TobiasFünke That was my first attempt as well, I thought that wouldn't work because I was not getting what I wanted overall....only realized I missed a square root on the normalization factor just now, another silly mistake. Thank you, it works out perfectly!
